# Join other tables with selected column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables
f11 the eacode,hcn,shsn is unique

```
f11 : eacode | hcn | shsn | age | sex | psc
f22 : eacode | hcn | shsn | etc | etc
```

i want to get in f11 table the age sex psc and match them on f22 eacode,hcn,shsn and all the columns.

i tried

```
SELECT age,psc,sex
FROM f11
RIGHT JOIN f22
ON f11.eacode=f22.eacode;
```

but it only see the age,sex,psc sorry for my bad english

Comment: You are seeing what you are selecting.

Comment: You have written `SELECT age,psc,sex`; `but it only see the age,sex,psc`. What exactly do you expect?

Comment: I WANT ON TABLE F22 WILL SEE ALL COLUMNS WITH THE COLUMNS ON F11 WHICH IS ONLY THE AGE SEX AND PSC

Comment: sorry im not yelling :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `RIGHT JOIN` here because it will list all records in table `f22` even if the `eacode` don't match.

What you need is an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.age, a.psc, a.sex,
        b.*                       -- << this will select all columns in F22
FROM    f11 a
        INNER JOIN f22 b
            ON a.eacode = b.eacode AND
               a.hcn = b.hcn AND
               a.shsn = b.shsn
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: will it match the hcn and shsn also?

Comment: no, only `eacode`. if you want to match with the other two, you need to have compound condition, eg. `a.eacode = b.eacode AND a.hcn = b.hcn AND a.shsn = b.shsn`

Comment: it did not match i want also to match this three eacode,hcn,shsn

Comment: this doesn't work? `SELECT  a.age, a.psc, a.sex,b.*                       
FROM    f11 a
        INNER JOIN f22 b
            ON a.eacode = b.eacode AND a.hcn = b.hcn AND a.shsn = b.shsn`